# jquery code works fine on jsfiddle but only partially (toggle doesnt work) on my website even though same version of jquery

Tags: jquery, toggle

I've been coding a element for my website on jsfiddle and when I tried to transfer it to my website (wordpress based), it only partially works.

It doesn't seem to be jquery itself not working because the expand/ collapse mechanics are working just fine. Something seems to be wrong with the class toggling and I'd appreciate if you'd help me out with this cuz I couldn't find a working solution by searching.

This is the code, jsfiddle tells me its valid - http://jsfiddle.net/GSzC4/

But on my website it doesn't work/ toggle doesnt work, the rest does - http://www.roxopolis.de/media/albums/what-would-you-give

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".content").hide();
    jQuery(".content_album").hide();

    jQuery(".heading").click(function () {
        jQuery(this).next(".content").slideToggle(200);
    });
    jQuery("#heading_album").click(function () {
        jQuery(this).next(".content_album").slideToggle(400);
    });

    $('#heading_album').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('album_clicked');
    });

    $('.heading').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('album_item_clicked');
    });
});
```

Comment: Why are you using both `$` and `jQuery` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change all you  `$` sign to `jquery` in your code... i think there occured a conflict between the jquery and other framework in wordpress

```
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('album_clicked');
  //^^^^---here
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help. Replacing $ with jquery fixed it. Works fine now, thx.